# Attempting to Pause JMS Queue Consumption from MessageBean fails to establish JMX Connection in WebLogic

Tags: queue, jms, message-queue, jmx, weblogic-10.x

I am trying to pause a JMS Queue from a **Message Driven Bean** on a weblogic server using JMX. The idea is that if the message fails to execute a set number of times then it pauses the queues consumption. When I attempt to connect via JMX it is failing, even though it is running within the WebLogic container.

Following is the code I am using, which fails on the call to `JMSRuntimeHelper.getJMSDestinationRuntimeMBean( ctx, queue );`

The code below works fine if I run it within a Session Facade bean called via a business delegate (i.e. t3/rmi connection).

```
Category access = OpenTwinsClientProperties.getInstance().getCategory( OpenTwinsClientProperties.CATEGORY_ACCESS );
String destinationAddresses = access.getValue( OpenTwinsClientProperties.ACCESS_PROVIDER_URL );
final String protocol = StringUtils.substringBefore( destinationAddresses, "://" );
destinationAddresses = StringUtils.removeStart( destinationAddresses, protocol );
final String[] destinations = StringUtils.split( destinationAddresses, ',' );
String[] hostAndPort = null;
for ( String destination : destinations ) {
    hostAndPort = destination.split( ":" );
}
JMXServiceURL serviceURL;
JMXConnector jmxConnection = null;
String jndiName = null;
try {
    serviceURL = new JMXServiceURL( protocol, hostAndPort[1].split( "//" )[1], Integer.parseInt( hostAndPort[2] ), "/jndi/" + DomainRuntimeServiceMBean.MBEANSERVER_JNDI_NAME );
    Hashtable<String, String> h = new Hashtable<String, String>();
    h.put( Context.SECURITY_PRINCIPAL, "weblogic" );
    h.put( Context.SECURITY_CREDENTIALS, "password1" );
    h.put( JMXConnectorFactory.PROTOCOL_PROVIDER_PACKAGES, "weblogic.management.remote" );
    MBeanServerConnection bco;
    jmxConnection = JMXConnectorFactory.connect( serviceURL, h );
    bco = jmxConnection.getMBeanServerConnection();

    InitialContext ctx = OpenTwinsFrontendUtilities.getInitialContext( false );
    //ctx.addToEnvironment( Context.SECURITY_PRINCIPAL, "weblogic" );
    //ctx.addToEnvironment( Context.SECURITY_CREDENTIALS, "password1" );
    Destination queue = (Destination) ctx.lookup( "jms/JMSAccessNotificationQueue" );

    JMSDestinationRuntimeMBean destMBean = JMSRuntimeHelper.getJMSDestinationRuntimeMBean( ctx, queue );
    destMBean.pauseProduction();
    destMBean.pauseConsumption();
} catch(NameNotFoundException ex){
    ex.printStackTrace();
} catch(Throwable ex){
    ex.printStackTrace();
} finally {
    if ( jmxConnection != null ) {
        try {
            jmxConnection.close();
        } catch ( IOException ex1 ) {
    }
}
```

Following is the exception message I get:

```
Caused By: javax.naming.NoPermissionException: User <anonymous> does not have permission on weblogic.management.mbeanservers to perform lookup operation.
    at weblogic.jndi.internal.ServerNamingNode.checkPermission(ServerNamingNode.java:449)
    at weblogic.jndi.internal.ServerNamingNode.checkLookup(ServerNamingNode.java:429)
    at weblogic.jndi.internal.ServerNamingNode.lookupHere(ServerNamingNode.java:180)
    at weblogic.jndi.internal.BasicNamingNode.lookup(BasicNamingNode.java:206)
    at weblogic.jndi.internal.BasicNamingNode.lookup(BasicNamingNode.java:220)
    at weblogic.jndi.internal.BasicNamingNode.lookup(BasicNamingNode.java:220)
    at weblogic.jndi.internal.WLEventContextImpl.lookup(WLEventContextImpl.java:254)
    at weblogic.jndi.internal.WLContextImpl.lookup(WLContextImpl.java:413)
    at javax.naming.InitialContext.lookup(InitialContext.java:392)
    at weblogic.management.remote.wlx.ClientProvider.findRMIServer(ClientProvider.java:131)
    at weblogic.management.remote.wlx.ClientProvider.newJMXConnector(ClientProvider.java:98)
    at javax.management.remote.JMXConnectorFactory.newJMXConnector(JMXConnectorFactory.java:339)
    at javax.management.remote.JMXConnectorFactory.connect(JMXConnectorFactory.java:248)
    at weblogic.jms.common.JMSEditHelper.lookupMBeanServerConnection(JMSEditHelper.java:79)
    at weblogic.jms.common.JMSEditHelper.getRuntimeService(JMSEditHelper.java:137)
    at weblogic.jms.common.JMSEditHelper.getDomainRuntimeService(JMSEditHelper.java:165)
```

- I have tried to provide the credentials in the initial context, but this made no difference.
- I have tried to tick *Anonymous Admin Lookup Enabled* in the WebLogic console, but this made no difference.

How can I gain the trust of the WebLogic container within a message driven bean so that I can pause the queue?